# How to output records in HTML table from moodle database?

Tags: moodle

I want to display data from moodle database in HTML table, but for every record separate table is being displayed:

Code:

```
$rec=$DB->get_records_sql('SELECT * FROM  `mdl_schedules`');
$table = new html_table();
$table->head = array('Date','Time', 'A' , 'B', 'C','D', 'E', 'F');
foreach ($rec as $records) {
$id = $records->id;
$scheduledatet = $records->scheduledate;
$scheduletime = $records->scheduletime;
$session = $records->s;
$venue = $records->v;
$trainer = $records->t;
$category = $records->c;
$course = $records->course;
$link = $records->link;
$table->data = array(array($scheduledatet, $scheduletime, $a,$b,$c,$d,$e,'<a href="'.$link.'">View</a>'));
echo html_writer::table($table);
}
```

Any reference or help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is old, but the reason you're only getting one record is you're not adding to the `$table->data` array. This is the code you want:

```
$rec=$DB->get_records('schedules');
$table = new html_table();
$table->head = array('Date','Time', 'A' , 'B', 'C','D', 'E', 'F');
foreach ($rec as $records) {
    $id = $records->id;
    $scheduledatet = $records->scheduledate;
    $scheduletime = $records->scheduletime;
    $session = $records->s;
    $venue = $records->v;
    $trainer = $records->t;
    $category = $records->c;
    $course = $records->course;
    $link = $records->link;
    $table->data[] = array($scheduledatet, $scheduletime, $a,$b,$c,$d,$e,'<a href="'.$link.'">View</a>');
}

echo html_writer::table($table);
```

I also changed up your query a bit. If you're just getting all of the records from a table, `$DB->get_records('TABLE_NAME_WITHOUT_PREFIX');` is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks @Doyle Lewis. I need your help on multi-select too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048476/moodle-multi-select-error

Answer (score 5):

The echo should be outside the loop :)

```
}
echo html_writer::table($table);
```

But you will probably want to use `flexible_table` instead so you can use pagination.

Have a look in /admin/localplugins.php for an example.

Comment: By placing the echo html_writer::table($table); outside loop it shows single record.